# How To Get Constant Inside ui-router (Angular) state function

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-service

I want to reference a "constant" that is defined outside this state function but if I try to pass it in as a provider it errors  because constants are not providers.  That is, I want to do something like:

```
var exports = module.exports = function ($stateProvider,configData) { ...
```

But that fails.  How can I get my javascript variable baseDirectory passed in.

The bigger problem is that the webroot is not always at the same url. sometimes it is /ng and sometimes it is just / and I want to be able to set that as a config someplace I can load into a config file (not hard code into the state function.

```
var exports = module.exports = function ($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: baseDirectory + '/home',
    templateUrl: '/templates/home/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeController',
  });
};
exports.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, what I did, is to build a constant in the app, and replace them with new value in gulp task when the base url changed.

It had many apps, so my idea is dumb and simple, just find and replace the value of the content in the app by the new value input from gulp task configuration.

It's not smart, but works.

In the example, I have three apps in /clinic, /panel, /company, and for each of them, it had a build.js in it.

The build.js will build the app, and replace the constant value.

I have many apps, so I do this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

var taskBuildClinic = require("./clinic/build");
var taskBuildPanel = require("./panel/build");
var taskBuildCompany = require("./company/build");

var migrate = require("./laravel/migrate");

var env = {
    'dev': {
        EndpointBaseUrl: "'/admin/public/';",
        TemplateBaseUrl: "'/admin/public';"
    }
};

// ./node_modules/.bin/gulp

gulp.task('clinic', function (cb) {

    return taskBuildClinic(gulp, env);
});

gulp.task('company', function (cb) {

    return taskBuildCompany(gulp, env);
});

gulp.task('panel', function (cb) {
    return taskBuildPanel(gulp, env);
});
```

In each build.js located in different app, it had:

```
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var replace = require('gulp-replace');
...

if (env['production']) {

    // replace something not for production

    endpoint = "var EndpointBaseUrl = " + env['production']['EndpointBaseUrl'];
    templateBaseUrl = "var TemplateBaseUrl = " + env['production']['TemplateBaseUrl'];
    console.log(endpoint);
    console.log(templateBaseUrl);

} else {

    endpoint = "var EndpointBaseUrl = " + env['dev']['EndpointBaseUrl'];
    templateBaseUrl = "var TemplateBaseUrl = " + env['dev']['TemplateBaseUrl'];
    console.log(endpoint);
}

return gulp.src(files)
    .pipe(concat(prefix + '.js'))
    .pipe(replace(/var EndpointBaseUrl.*?;/g, endpoint))
    .pipe(replace(/var TemplateBaseUrl.*?;/g, templateBaseUrl))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
```

In the app, I had:

```
var TemplateBaseUrl = "";
var EndpointBaseUrl = "";
```

Their content will be replaced by the value from gulp task.

Comment: Thanks @Tom for the detailed answer.  Very clever.  After I posted, I did run into a solution that solves my problem but not sure if yours.  In the index.html page (which I do dynamically created from asp.net) I found that if I put <base href="/ngrun/"> that my url's all work with that base.

Comment: @PeterKellner thats good too, actually by using server side script is better, I just try to use pure js there, and it looks dumb..